# How I can assign alternate stack for SIGSEGV?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, signals, systems-programming

I'm registering SIGSEGV (for Segmentation fault) Using `sigaction()` function. It working in all cases but except one case i.e. when stack is overflowing.I searched to resolve this problem. Then I get the answer, we have to assign alternate Stack. But I don't know how to assign altrenate stack for signal registration. Please help me to allocate alternate stack for segmenaion fault step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `sigaltstack`.

```
stack_t stack = {
    .ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ),
    .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ,
    .ss_flags = 0
};

if (sigaltstack(&stack, NULL))
    perror("sigaltstack");
```

At this point just establish your signal handler with `sigaction` and use `sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK`.

Answer (score -1):

First establish an alternative stack with [sigaltstack](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaltstack.html)()

Secondly, when installing the signal handler, use [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html)() and set the SA_ONSTACK in the `sa_flags` member of the struct sigaction.